# On groups of order $6n$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite group such that $|\operatorname{Inn}(G)|=6$ and $Z(G)$ is an elementary abelian $2$-group of order $2^n$. Then prove or disprove that $G$ is isomorphic to $$\underbrace{C_{2}\times...\times C_{2}}_{n-1}\times D_{12}\hspace{10pt} \mathrm{or}\hspace{10pt} \underbrace{C_{2}\times...\times C_{2}}_{n-1}\times T,$$ where $D_{12}$ is the dihedral group of order 12 and $T=C_{3}\rtimes C_{4}$.

Attempt: This is true for groups of order $12$, $24$, $48$ or $96$. I think this is true in general.

Comment: Yes I think it is true. Here are some suggestions. Prove that $G$ has a normal Sylow 3-subgroup and an abelian Sylow 2-subgroup, which must be $C_2^{n+1}$ or $C_2^n \times C_4$, giving the two cases. Note also that $D_{12} \cong D_6 \times C_2$.

Comment: @ Derek Holt: your hint is very nice. I think since $S_{3}$ has only one subgroup of order 3. Hence, we can conclude that Sylow 3-subgroup of $G$ is normal. I do not know why Sylow 2-subgroup of $G$ is abelian?  But if it is abelian then it must be $C_{2}^{n+1}$ or $C_{2}^{n-1}\times C_{4}$, since $exp(G)$ is at most 12. Now by Schur-Zassenhaus Theorem, we have $$C_{3}\rtimes C_{2}^{n+1}\hspace{10pt} or \hspace{10pt} C_{3}\rtimes (C_{4}\times C_{2}^{n-1}).$$ Now do we can say these are the result?

Comment: The Sylow 2-subgroup $S$ is abelian, because $S/Z(S)$ has order 2 and hence is cyclic. For the semidirect products, remember that the subgroup $Z(G)$  of index 2 in $S$ centralizes $C_3$, and elements in $S \setminus Z(G)$ invert the generator of $T$, so in fact the actions in the semidirect products are uniquely determined, and hence there is a unique group in both cases.

Comment: In this case yes, because we know that the subgroup $C_2^{n-1}$ is in the centre.

Comment: @ Derek Holt: if $H, K, M$ be subgroups of a group $G$ such that $M\subseteq Z(G)$, then do we can say $H\rtimes (K\times M)\cong(H\rtimes K)\times M$?

Comment: Yes that is correct.

Comment: @maryam: Nice question. It needs to be reflected more and more. +1

Answer (score 1):

If $n=0$, $S_3$ is a counter example. So we may assume that $n>0$.
We know that $G/Z(G)\cong \mathrm{Inn}(G)$, so by our assumption we get that $G/Z(G)\cong S_{3}$, since $G/Z(G)\cong C_{6}$ results in $G=Z(G)$, a contradiction.
We prove that $G$ has a normal Sylow $3$- subgroup.
As $PZ(G)\le N_{G}(P)$, where $P$ is a Sylow $3$-subgroup of $G$, we see that $|G:N_{G}(P)|\le2$. If $|G:N_{G}(P)|=2$, then $G=N_{G}(N_{G}(P))=N_{G}(P)$, a contradiction. Hence $P\triangleleft G$. So $G\cong C_{3}\rtimes Q$, where $Q$ is a Sylow $2$-subgroup of $G$, and acts non-trivially on $P$. Now we prove that $Q$ is abelian. By the assumption, $Z(G)\le Q$, whence $Z(G)\le Z(Q)$, and $|P:Z(Q)|\le 2$. Obviously $|Q:Z(Q)|\ne 2$, therefore $Q$ is abelian. Remark that $Z(G)$ is a maximal subgroup of $Q$. Hence $Q\cong C_{2}^{n+1}\cong Z(G)\times C_{2}$, or $Q\cong H\times C_{4}$, where $H< Z(G)$.

Case 1) If $Q\cong Z(G)\times C_{2}$, then $G\cong C_{3}\rtimes (Z(G)\times C_{2})\cong Z(G)\times (C_{3}\rtimes C_{2})$, note that the $C_{2}$ acts on $C_{3}$ non-trivially, if not $G\cong P\times Q$, a contradiction. As we know $C_{3}\rtimes C_{2}\cong S_{3}$, therefore $G\cong Z(G)\times S_{3}\cong C_{2}^{n-1}\times D_{12}$, as wanted.

Case 2) If $Q\cong H\times C_{4}$, then $G\cong C_{3}\rtimes (H\times C_{4})\cong H\times (C_{3}\rtimes C_{4})$. Remark that by the same discussion in Case 1, $C_{4}$ acts non-trivially on $C_{3}$. So $G\cong H\times T$, as we wished.

Comment: I just proved the claims and hints by @DerekHolt in the comment section.

Comment: Looking at this again, it occurs to me that we could have $G=S_3$ with $n=0$, which would make the statement false.

Comment: @DerekHolt $Z(S_3)=1$. We assumed that $Z(G)$ is elementary abelian $2$-group. I think in most of the books they don’t consider the trivial group as a $p$-group.

Comment: I don't think that is true. I just checked in the textbooks by Isaacs, Rotman and Robinson, and none of them require $p$-groups to be nontrivial. On the contrary, these and other books state the theorem "A nontrivial finite $p$-group has nontrivial center". Isaacs remarks explicitly that the trivial group is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of a finite group with order not divisible by $p$.

Comment: @DerekHolt You’re right. I just checked some other references the term “non-trivial $p$-group” means that they consider the trivial group a $p$-group. But about this problem, seems like $n> 0$, because she stated that this conjecture is true for groups of order $12, 24, …$ and also we don’t have the direct product of $-1$ number of $C_{2}$ to my knowledge. So we add $n>0$ to avoid our lovely $S_3$ who’s everywhere. :) Thanks for the heads up

Comment: Yes I agree you need to add $n>0$ to the assumptions.

Comment: @DerekHolt just added that assumption. There’s another way to correct it, as you mentioned $D_{12}\cong S_{3}\times C_{2}$, We just need to replace $D_{12}$ by $S_{3}$ in the statment. That way we don’t need any additional assumptions.